# Best "free" JMS implementation (that doesn't crash all the time)

Tags: java, jms, messaging

What is the best *free*, or *GNU* licensed JMS server. We want something that is easy to install and will "just work" without too much intervention on our part.

We are open to other non JMS and even non Java messing solutions, but there would have to be a compelling reason to use a different non Java based solution with our Java applications. It should also be lightweight, SOAP for example does not perform well when you are dealing with millions of messages.

#### Background

We have already had one foray into doing messaging using Active MQ. It turned out to be great except for the fact that Active MQ would mysteriously die every few days with no clues as to what went wrong. We were probably averaging about 1-2 million messages per day. We ended up canning the solution because we need something that is not going to fall over every other night when we are in bed.

Comment: NB: We are re-evaluating Active MQ, but naturally our past bad experiences has tainted our perspective

Comment: What version of Active MQ are you using?

Comment: Check out http://openjms.sourceforge.net/ or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Lingo](http://lingo.codehaus.org/).  I haven't run into any issues with Active MQ though.  How was it failing?

EDIT:

Lingo is dead, ignore that portion of my response.

Comment: It would just disappear from memory, with no information in any log files that we could find.

Comment: Lingo web site says there are no current developers or maintainers and the link to the online source code repository for the project doesn't work. http://lingo.codehaus.org/lingo/team-list.html

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it recently, it looks like it's dead.  What do you mean by disappear from memory?  From viewing the processes?  What log files did you look into?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RedHat's JBoss HornetMQ or RabbitMQ?

Comment: Sorry for the simplistic answer. I'm working from my mobile phone.

Comment: I have seen/heard of these. We were hoping that rather than having to try each one of them and learn all of them to make an informed decision, there might be some people who have experience using them and can provide a recommendation/wisdom based on experience.

Comment: @corydoras, to make informed decisions, you will have to setup these JMS solutions to the specification you want and create test cases to see what satisfies your criteria. Different users can have different perception or different love for MQ.

Comment: Yes but we can still use stackoverflow to share experiences and learn from each other. For example if enough experienced people report that they use WebLogic JMS que, and it intermittently falls over, that has got to be of help to others. I don't want to waste time trying to evaluate solutions that are known to be bad for whatever reason.

Comment: RabbitMQ supports JMS, but i weirdly not in java. This might or might not be a problem.

Comment: We have lots of experience with HornetQ, and it works very fast and reliable, but we could crash it by combining high load with server reboots and network disconnections.